# FastCGI com C++ e NGINX

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

Estou tentando fazer um pequeno servidor para estudo usando fastCGI com C++ sem o uso de qualquer biblioteca. O meu problema é que via socket o NGINX até conecta mas não me passa informação alguma sobre a requisição, e se eu escrever algum callback ele gera erro 502.

**OBS:**  Estou usando uma class Socket que criei. https://github.com/TigreFramework/Network

Eis meu código C++.

```
#include "Socket.h"
#include "thread"


using namespace Tigre;


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char** envp)  {
    try {
        Socket *s = new Socket("localhost", 9000, TCP);
        s->Bind(5);
        std::cout << "Esperando Cliente\n";
        Socket *cliente = s->Accept();
        //cliente->Write("\r\n");
        //cliente->Write("Bem vindo ao servidor!");
        std::cout << "Esperando Mensagem do Cliente\n";

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 100) {
            std::cout << "'"<< cliente->Read() << "'" << "\n";
            i++;
        }
    }catch (SocketException &e){
        std:cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

Configuração do NGINX:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
            root           share/nginx/html;

            fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}

}
```

**EDIT1:** Fiz uma alteração na linha `std::cout << "'"<< cliente->Read() << "'" << "\n";` para verificar se chegava alguma valor em branco, e realmente chega como podem ver abaixo.
**OBS2** O erro só ocorre quando o Nginx gera o erro 502 e retorna para o browser.

Console:

```
Esperando Cliente
Esperando Mensagem do Cliente
''
'Sem conexão com o Socket.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: em sua classe Socket o comando "socket_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);" é estranho, normalmente no lugar do "6" usa-se "0"; talvez até funcione, mas é estranho; agora, para depurar sua aplicação sugiro um analisador de rede tipo tcpdump ou wireshark

Comment: Fiz a correção de "6" para "0", mas o resultado foi o mesmo. O engraçado que se eu uso o telnet para se conectar funciona perfeitamente, e se eu abrir via browser direto na porta 9000 eu recebo todo o cabeçalho web.

Comment: O `Socket *cliente = s->Accept();` não deveria estar dentro de um loop?

Comment: Sim, mas como fica travado dentro do `std::cout << cliente->Read() <<  "\n";` nunca chegaria a esperar um novo cliente, a não ser que eu adicione cada novo cliente em uma nova `thread`.

Comment: @PedroSoares só uma observação: se quiser atender vários clientes sem threads precisa do loop e conexão não bloqueante. Uma state machine é um jeito bom de gerenciar isso. Se tiver nova conexão você armazena em uma lista, e vai atendendo cada uma delas alternadamente (sempre checando por novas conexões também, e retirando conexões encerradas da lista em seguida).

Comment: @Bacco disso eu sei, mas neste caso como eu nem recebo informação do Nginx ainda não me preocupei com o acesso mais de 1 Cliente, além do mais irei criar uma `Thread Pool` quando resolver este problema. Mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: @PedroSoares sim, mas como está tudo simples e rodando em um "console" e não "GUI" não vejo como isso irá bloquear de fato, claro que não será uma coisa eficiente, mas ainda sim tem que existir um observador para detectar dados recebidos pelo Accept. Creio eu.